# Did std::bind implement std::ref and std::cref to disambiguate the function call?

Tags: c++, function, overloading, stdbind

I know that I shouldn't overload a function for just parameters differ only in one of them passed by copy and the other by reference:

```
void foo(int x)
{
    cout << "in foo(int x) x: " << x << endl;
}
void foo(int& x)
{
    cout << "in foo(int& x) x: " << x << endl;
}

int main()
{

    int a = 1;
    foo(5); // ok as long as there is one best match foo(int)
    foo(a); // error: two best candidates so the call is ambiguous
    //foo(std::move(a));
    //foo(std::ref(an)); // why also this doesn't work?
}
```

So a code that uses `std::bind` can be like this:

```
std::ostream& printVec(std::ostream& out, const std::vector<int> v)
{
    for (auto i : v)
        out << i << ", ";
    return out;
}

int main()
{
    //auto func = std::bind(std::cout, std::placeholders::_1); // error: stream objects cannot be passed by value
    auto func = std::bind(std::ref(std::cout), std::placeholders::_1); // ok. 

}
```

So `std::ref` here to ensure passing by reference rather than by value to avoid ambiguity?
* The thing that matters me: Does `std::bind()` implemented some wrapper to overcome this issue?

- Why I can't use `std::ref` in my example to help the compiler in function matching?

Comment: I don't see any code containing `std::bind` in your question.  Please clarify what you are talking about.  I suspect you are completely misunderstanding how std bind and std ref interact, but I cannot tell how you are misunderstanding it.  So please provide an example of std bind and std ref interacting in the way you think they do (and overloading).

Comment: `std::ref` returns `std::reference_wrapper` so a conversion is still needed.  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont: Edited.

Answer (score 2):

Now that you know passing by value and reference are ambiguous when overload resolution tries to compare them for choosing a best viable function, let's answer how would you use `std::ref` (or `std::cref`) to differentiate between pass-by-value and pass-by-reference.

It turns out to be ... pretty simple. Just write the overloads such that one accepts a `int`, and the other accepts a `std::reference_wrapper<int>`:

```cpp
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

void foo(int x) {
    std::cout << "Passed by value.\n";
}

void foo(std::reference_wrapper<int> x) {
    std::cout << "Passed by reference.\n";
    int& ref_x = x;
    ref_x = 42;
    /*  Do whatever you want with ref_x.  */
}

int main() {
    int x = 0;
    foo(x);
    foo(std::ref(x));
    std::cout << x << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> Passed by value.
>
> Passed by reference.
>
> 42

The function pass the argument by value by default. If you want to pass by reference, use `std::ref` explicitly.

Now let's answer your second question: how does `std::bind` deal with this type of scenario. Here is a simple demo I have created:

```cpp
#include <functional>
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct Storage {
    T data;
};

template <typename T>
struct unwrap_reference {
    using type = T;
};

template <typename T>
struct unwrap_reference<std::reference_wrapper<T>> {
    using type = std::add_lvalue_reference_t<T>;
};

template <typename T>
using transform_to_storage_type = Storage<typename unwrap_reference<std::decay_t<T>>::type>;

template <typename T>
auto make_storage(T&& obj) -> transform_to_storage_type<T> {
    return transform_to_storage_type<T> { std::forward<T>(obj) };
}

int main() {
    int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0;
    auto storage_a = make_storage(a);
    auto storage_b = make_storage(std::ref(b));
    auto storage_c = make_storage(std::cref(c));

    storage_a.data = 42;
    storage_b.data = 42;
    // storage_c.data = 42;         // Compile error: Cannot modify const.

    // 0 42 0
    std::cout << a << " " << b << " " << c << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

It is not `std::bind`, but the method used is similar (it's also similar to `std::make_tuple`, which has the same semantic). `make_storage` by default copies the parameter, unless you explicitly use `std::ref`.

As you can see, `std::ref` is not magic. You need to do something extra for it to work, which in our case is to first decay the type (all references are removed in this process), and then check whether the final type is a `reference_wrapper` or not; if it is, unwrap it.